# Error:(33, 0) Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.1]

Tags: android, firebase

Trying to configure Firebase for my android project. But I get sync error.

`build.gradle` app directory:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yunus.relichunter"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.1'

}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`build.gradle` root directory :

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[image]

You can see the error on the image shown above. 
I have tried to install Firebase using its assistance (tools/Firebase) then I tried to do it normally.

Comment: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.1'` does not belong in your app gradle. remove it

Answer (score 1):

As @tyczj says, you can't use `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.1'` in your **module** build.gradle (like app module) dependencies block. You only can use it in your **project** or **root** build.gradle dependencies block.